# My Android App Crashes After Pressing the Home Button

Tags: android

i have an activity which has a scrollview and MediaPlayer, while the music is playing and i press home, it closed normal, but when i press the home button without the music or anything else the app stop running, please help, there's a code or method to avoid this problem? I'm new in android

**Here is my logcat**

```
    01-15 18:05:39.713: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:39.992: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:39.992: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:40.462: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 39K, 7% free 2425K/2584K, paused 65ms, total 76ms
01-15 18:05:40.502: I/dalvikvm-heap(795): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.945MB for 1536016-byte allocation
01-15 18:05:40.571: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 3924K/4088K, paused 68ms, total 68ms
01-15 18:05:40.682: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 3924K/4088K, paused 18ms+19ms, total 116ms
01-15 18:05:41.272: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 3924K/4088K, paused 46ms, total 46ms
01-15 18:05:41.332: I/dalvikvm-heap(795): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.239MB for 3456016-byte allocation
01-15 18:05:41.443: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 3% free 7299K/7464K, paused 24ms+17ms, total 110ms
01-15 18:05:41.711: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:41.711: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:41.741: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:41.782: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:41.932: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:41.942: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:41.961: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:42.021: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:42.021: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:42.071: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:42.071: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:42.071: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:42.091: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:42.131: D/gralloc_goldfish(795): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-15 18:05:42.302: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:42.411: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:45.321: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:45.331: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:45.352: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:45.352: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:45.422: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:45.431: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:45.461: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:45.492: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:45.601: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:45.711: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:45.711: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:45.711: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:45.981: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:45.981: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:45.991: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:46.681: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:46.721: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:46.751: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:46.812: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:47.031: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:47.041: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:47.061: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:47.061: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:47.081: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:47.221: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:47.221: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:47.273: I/Choreographer(795): Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-15 18:05:47.281: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:47.301: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:47.321: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:47.321: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:47.332: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:47.332: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:47.631: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:47.781: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:47.843: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:48.081: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:48.081: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:48.091: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:48.121: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:48.471: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:48.481: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:48.481: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:48.492: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:48.543: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:48.871: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:48.871: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:48.911: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:48.911: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:48.991: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:48.991: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:49.221: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:49.251: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:49.431: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:49.441: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:49.461: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:49.471: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:49.471: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:49.471: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:49.551: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:49.551: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:49.662: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:49.751: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:49.751: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:49.761: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:49.852: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:49.852: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:49.852: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:50.751: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1578K, 21% free 6643K/8340K, paused 265ms, total 293ms
01-15 18:05:50.761: I/dalvikvm-heap(795): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.063MB for 1536016-byte allocation
01-15 18:05:51.052: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 3% free 8138K/8340K, paused 8ms+66ms, total 270ms
01-15 18:05:51.582: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 8138K/8340K, paused 229ms, total 229ms
01-15 18:05:51.812: I/dalvikvm-heap(795): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.354MB for 3456016-byte allocation
01-15 18:05:52.143: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 11513K/11716K, paused 88ms+58ms, total 330ms
01-15 18:05:52.773: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:52.802: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:52.872: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:52.962: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:53.182: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:53.202: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:53.212: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:53.222: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:53.222: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:53.343: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:53.343: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:53.362: I/Choreographer(795): Skipped 148 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-15 18:05:53.362: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:53.393: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:53.922: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:54.022: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:54.102: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:54.102: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:54.182: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:54.182: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:54.212: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:54.212: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:54.593: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:54.852: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:54.852: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:55.042: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:55.132: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:55.132: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:55.252: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:55.281: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:55.281: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:55.322: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:55.392: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:55.392: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:55.392: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:55.392: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:55.422: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:55.422: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:55.472: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:55.483: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:55.492: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:05:55.492: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:06:06.813: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 18:06:06.842: D/AndroidRuntime(795): Shutting down VM
01-15 18:06:06.842: W/dalvikvm(795): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.storyteller/com.example.storyteller.Ricitos}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3016)
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2971)
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2949)
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1245)
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.example.storyteller.Ricitos.onPause(Ricitos.java:63)
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5206)
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1226)
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3002)
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  ... 12 more
01-15 18:06:11.002: I/Process(795): Sending signal. PID: 795 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please post the (red) LogCat output and the relevant code you're using. We haven't memorized every `MediaPlayer` error in existence... yet.

Comment: 01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 18:06:06.991: E/AndroidRuntime(795):  at com.example.storyteller.Ricitos.onPause(Ricitos.java:63) this is what causing the problem

Comment: but how to solve it? @deville

Comment: @Whady, yes, `NullPointerException` at line 63 of your `Ricitos.java`. For any further assistance, post your `onPause()` method

Comment: public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mp.pause();
       
    }


 public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
        System.exit(0);     
        }
 @deville

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose, the "Home button" is your phone home button. You probably have an error in your onPause or onDestroy method. Send us your error log.

Comment: as you see, there is an error in your onPause method. add here your onPause method

Comment: there it is! :) public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mp.pause();
       
    }


 public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
        System.exit(0);     
        } @gezdy

Comment: Try this `public void onPause() { super.onPause(); if (mp != null) mp.pause(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Check your `onDestroy()` and `onPause()` methods. Probabily you are not closing the MediaPlayer.

Comment: the mediaplayer close after press home, the problem is when the media is not playing i press the button and crashes @gavrielaugusto

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onPause() { 
    super.onPause(); 
    mp.pause(); 
}
```

The only possible cause of `NullPointerException` here is `mp` being `null`. Check if you assign `null` to it anywhere in your code or if you initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

I've also met the same problem .. The simple solution is just implement onPause() method and put your stop code there ....