# In Android, how to resume music after returning from pressing back/home button

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In Android, When I press back/home button the music stops (that's fine), but when I re-enter to the activity I want to begin/resume playing back the music.

How does Android manage playback of audio when the program goes into the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinarily, you should include a lot more details and code about your problem, but I just happened to see your other post on a [related matter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14343834/1904517).

You need the following in `onResume()`.  Note, if you are doing `mp.start()` in `onCreate()`, you can remove that start as `onResume()` is called after `onCreate()`.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if(mp != null && !mp.isPlaying())
        mp.start();
    super.onResume();
}
```

`start()` from `MeidaPlayer` will start over if stop or never played, or from where paused if it was paused.

Comment: the code is in the question now :), can you add the method that you are trying to explain me? @iagreen

Comment: it works when i press the home button :), but no with the back button @iagreen

Comment: That is true -- if you press the back button, your `Activity` is destroyed, not paused.  To start again, you will have to save more persistent state. See @Ed's comment about the current behavior being the one expected by the user -- that is "back" = "quit" for the user.

Answer (score 2):

The code given below only works if the activity hasn't been destroyed. If you want to survive when the user presses the back button, you'll have to write the current status of the media player out to a file, and reload it when the activity starts again.

I'm not sure that's the correct behavior though. After the back button is pressed, your application SHOULD terminate, and start up next time in a reset state. I think. If the back button gets used for navigation in your app, the solution is to put up an alert asking of the user REALLY REALLY wants to quit, on the final back button that terminates the app. Override 
Activity.onBackPressed to customize the behavior of the back button.

Note also that your activity can be destroyed even in paused state, if the system is looking for more memory, if the screen flips, or if several other high-level system states change. To deal with this case, you need to implement savedInstanceState handling. Implement Activity.onSaveInstanceState, and then look for a non-null savedInstanceState parameter in your implementation of onCreate.

In both cases, you're going to have to implement some method for recreating the media player, preparing the audio again, and seeking to the correct position in the resurrected audio.

Comment: so you are saying that i can add a window with an alert message when the user press the back button right? that's a good idea, but if there's some code or method that satisfy my question (about the back button) would be great if I incorporate it to my code @Ed Rowland

Comment: Too complicate to cook up source-code for an Alert here. Basic plot summary is to show the alert in the override of onBackPressed, and return true to indicate that you've handled it. The OnClick handler for the positive button in the alert should call Activity.finish() to terminate the activity.

Answer (score 0):

add this method,

```
  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
if(mp != null)
   mp.start();
}
```